# NET CORE 2.0 Put IHtmlLocalizer in _Layout and use it in .cshtml files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a question. Localization is working in my application correctly but it feels a bit clunky.

I mean, is there a way to put all of these imports and injections in _Layout.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization;
@using Voxel.WebApis.IDP.Resources;
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<General> GeneralLocalizer;
```

And use my GeneralLocalizer in the rest of pages? Or i have to put all the "injection" and "using" code in every .cshtml i want to localize?

Right now parser error forces me to copy paste the code in every .cshtml i want to put translations...

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much exactly what `_ViewImports.cshtml` is for.

Comment: Wow, i feel like an ignorant right now. Im just new at .net core.

It works like a charm. Thank you very much for your answer!